# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oracle.forms.handler.IHandler.getApplet()Ljava/applet/Applet

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

Woking on Oracle Forms v 10.1.2.3.0, The Form works in most of the system, but in some systems getting this error

basic: updateValidationResultsForApplet update
cache: Mark prevalidated: http://www.url.com/forms/java/frmwebutil.jar true tm=1392121370281 cert=1370584360000
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions CeilingPolicy allPerms
Exception in thread "thread applet-oracle.forms.engine.Main-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oracle.forms.handler.IHandler.getApplet()Ljava/applet/Applet;
    at oracle.forms.webutil.common.VBeanCommon.init(VBeanCommon.java:281)
    at oracle.forms.handler.UICommon.instantiate(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.handler.UICommon.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.handler.JavaContainer.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.onCreateHandler(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.processSet(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.onMessageReal(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.onMessage(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.sendInitialMessage(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.startRunform(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Main.createRunform(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.forms.engine.Main.start(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Thanks

Comment: By system you mean OS ? Try to be more specific with your question. Check Java versions.

Comment: @DARK_A No issue resolved it myself, It was just the old frmwebutil.jar in java cache that was causing the problem, and the system was a windows XP 32 bit